# Prevent repaint of absolute/relative named views using ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, url-routing

I have a site where there are three separate areas of content:

- content
- sidebar
- lightbox

I want to load a different piece of content into each area depending on the url e.g.

- /content/1/
- /sidebar/details/
- /lightbox/videos/

This is relatively easy using angularjs and adding the ui-router plugin. However it has an undesired behaviour. Whenever I load a template into one area, the other areas all reset their content back to the original route. I would like to preserve the state of each separately, without reloading the content.

I understand that this functionality may be possible by targeting child views using absolute and relative names, this seems to work for one child but not when I add another.

```
    .state('index', {
        url: "",
        views: {
            "main@": {
                templateUrl: "content.html"
            },
            "lightbox@index": {
                templateUrl: "lightbox1.html"
            },
            "content@index": {
                templateUrl: "viewA.html"
            },
            "sidebar@index": {
                templateUrl: "sidebar.html"
            }
        }
    })
    .state('index.content1', {
        url: "/content1",
        views: {
            "content@index": {
                templateUrl: "viewA.html"
            }
        }
    })
    .state('index.content2', {
        url: "/content2",
        views: {
            "content@index": {
                templateUrl: "viewB.html"
            }
        }
    })
    .state('index.sidebar1', {
        url: "/sidebar1",
        views: {
            "sidebar@index": {
                templateUrl: "sidebar.html"
            }
        }
    })
    .state('index.sidebar2', {
        url: "/sidebar2",
        views: {
            "sidebar@index": {
                templateUrl: "sidebar2.html"
            }
        }
    })
    .state('index.lightbox1', {
        url: "/lightbox1",
        views: {
            "lightbox@index": {
                templateUrl: "lightbox1.html"
            }
        }
    })
    .state('index.lightbox2', {
        url: "/lightbox2",
        views: {
            "lightbox@index": {
                templateUrl: "lightbox2.html"
            }
        }
    })
```

My example has some success but:

- Clicking sidebar2 and lightbox2 one resets the other one
- Changing the parent content area it resets the other two
- Controller to show the javascript is being inited at the correct time
- Textarea (without ng-bind) that you can type in to observe template being re-rendered

http://plnkr.co/edit/BCkCVak3ezinz81lLPnd?p=preview

Just a note on how I would do achieve this as native JavaScript (easy!):

```
function addEvent(name, el, func) {
    if (el.addEventListener) {
        el.addEventListener(name, func, false);
    } else if (el.attachEvent) {
        el.attachEvent('on' + name, func);
    } else {
        el[name] = func;
    }
}

function checkUrl() {
    var sections = window.location.hash.slice(2).split('/'),
        target = document.getElementById(sections[0]),
        source = sections[1] + '.html';
    if (target && source) {
        load(source, function (data) {
            target.innerHTML = source.innerHTML;
        });
    }
}

function load(url, callback) {
    var me = this,
        xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', url, true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                callback(xhr.responseText);
            } else {
                callback('error');
            }
        }
    };
    xhr.send();
}

addEvent('hashchange', window, function (e) {
    checkUrl();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I added UI-Router Extras, rearranged your states, and made the three viewports "sticky".  I wasn't sure how you intended the states/views to interact, so I made all three views separate, instead of the sidebar being a nested view inside the content.

I also wasn't sure what content you wanted loaded by default in the three viewports, so I used ng-include.

http://plnkr.co/edit/Fh9WWSbNWsioKYupP0tX?p=preview

Read more about sticky states  here: http://christopherthielen.github.io/ui-router-extras/example/sticky/#/

```
<div ui-view="main"></div>
<div class="row">
<div class="span6" ui-view="content">
  <!-- default content, before any states are active -- note, no controller-->
  <div ng-include="'viewA.html'"></div>
</div>
<div class="span6" ui-view="sidebar">
  <!-- default content, before any states are active -- note, no controller-->
  <div ng-include="'sidebar.html'"></div>
</div>

</div>
<div ui-view="lightbox">
  <!-- default content, before any states are active -- note, no controller-->
  <div ng-include="'lightbox1.html'"></div>
</div>
```

---

```
$stateProvider
    .state('index', {
        url: "",
        views: {
            "main@": {
                templateUrl: "content.html"
            }
        }
    })
    .state('index.content', { url: "", sticky: true, views: { 'content@': { template: '<ui-view/>' } } })
    .state('index.content.1', {
        url: "/content1",
        templateUrl: "viewA.html"
    })
    .state('index.content.2', {
        url: "/content2",
        templateUrl: "viewB.html"
    })
    .state('index.sidebar', { url: "", sticky: true, views: { 'sidebar@': { template: '<ui-view/>' } } })
    .state('index.sidebar.1', {
        url: "/sidebar1",
        templateUrl: "sidebar.html"
    })
    .state('index.sidebar.2', {
        url: "/sidebar2",
        templateUrl: "sidebar2.html"
    })
    .state('index.lightbox', { url: "", sticky: true, views: { 'lightbox@': { template: '<ui-view/>' } } })
    .state('index.lightbox.1', {
        url: "/lightbox1",
        templateUrl: "lightbox1.html"
    })
    .state('index.lightbox.2', {
        url: "/lightbox2",
        templateUrl: "lightbox2.html"
    })
})
```